# Apply CSS Repeatedly to Specific Words

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to apply CSS repeatedly and automatically to specific words.

For example, for the word "Twitter" I want the colour of the text to be #00ACED.

At present I am manually applying these colours around specific brand terms using span classes:

```
<span class="twitter">Twitter</span>
```

With the CSS:

```
.twitter {
    color: #00ACED;
}
```

However, this is a process and I would prefer a method which completes this styling automatically. I have about 20 brand words with an associated colour styling.

Can anyone assist me with this problem. I am using WordPress if that makes any difference.

Comment: Use JS to achieve this.

Comment: You'd be better in the long run to prefix those classes. "word-twitter" instead of just "twitter", for instance. Otherwise you may have issues with future styling.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly sorry I'm not too proficient coding website, I'm more  involved with design side. Could you explain this in a simpler way? How would you change what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straight-forward way to do it is by using a smart [jQuery highlight](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) plugin I came across. After applying it, you'll be able to do what you're after. Below is an example, with a link to a live fiddle at the end:

**HTML**

```
<p>Some examples of how to highlight words with the jQuery Highlight plugin. First an example to demonstrate the default behavior and then others to demonstrate how to highlight the words Facebook and Twitter with their own class names. Words will be highlighted anywhere in the DOM, one needs only to be specific on where the script should look for the words. It supports case-sensitivity and other options, like in the case of YouTube.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p { line-height: 30px; }
span { padding: 4px; }
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
.facebook { background-color: #3c528f; color: white; }
.twitter { background-color: #1e9ae9; color: white; }
.youtube { background-color: #be0017; color: white; }
```

**Highlight Plugin** (needs to be loaded after `jQuery` and before the `JavaScript` below)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/bartaz/sandbox.js/raw/master/jquery.highlight.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
// default
$("body p").highlight("default");
// specify class name (not case sensitive)
$("body p").highlight("twitter", { className: 'twitter' });
$("body p").highlight("facebook", { className: 'facebook' });
// specify class name (case sensitive)
$("body p").highlight("YouTube", { className: 'youtube', caseSensitive: true });
```

Include this `JavaScript` at the bottom of the page (before the `body` closing tag so that you don't need to use the function below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // unnecessary if you load all your scripts at the bottom of your page
});
```

[Fiddle for the win](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/SckjL/)! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work. You would have to loop through your search terms and this might not be the most effective way to do it.

```
function add_class (search, replacement) {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
         var text = all[i].textContent || all[i].innerText;
         if (text.indexOf(search) !== -1 && ! all[i].hasChildNodes()) {
            all[i].className = all[i].className + " " + replacement;
         }
    }
}

var replacements = [
    ["Twitter","twitter"],
    //
]

for (var i = replacements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    add_class(replacements[i][0],replacements[i][1]);
};
```

**Note:** I didn't test this at all.

Comment: thanks you for your suggestions. Can this code simply be copied into the functions.php file of WordPress or do I need to make additions to it?

Comment: You'll want to throw it in between some script tags. Maybe have it wait until after the DOM loads. You'll also want to check it for bugs in the JS console.

Comment: This is `JavaScript` @jordanhuxley, not `PHP`. you'd be better off putting it on a dedicated `.js` file and including it just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @Ethan, close the parenthesis you opened after the last `add_class`. ;)

Comment: I've created a separate JS file and inserted before the closing </body> tag, however, the styling has not been applied to the term "Twitter".

Answer (score 0):

If you know minimum among of JavaScript, this JavaScript library can make your life much easier. it will convert all the letter in the string into a span tag.  http://daverupert.com/2010/09/lettering-js/

Answer (score 0):

For those of you interested in the answer, I've created a solution using WordPress functionality:

```
function replace_custom_word($text){
    $replace = array(
    'Twitter' => '<span class="twitter"><a title="Twitter" target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/">Twitter</a></span>',
    'Facebook' => '<span class="facebook"><a title="Facebook" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></span>'
    );

$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
return $text;}
```